# Get SQL String substituted with parameters using java

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, elasticsearch

Is there any easy way to get a completed SQL statement after parameter substitution?

I am using elasticsearch-sql to query elastic search with sql statements, however I have to submit the query with all the parameters substituted.

I tried Hibernate Query `getQueryString`, but the parameter substitution is not happening for those sql strings.

The following sql string is produced:

> "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME=? AND SURNAME=?"

rather than:

> "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME='Selva' AND SURNAME='Esra'

Appreciate any better idea/thoughts?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, how did you get the first sql string?

Comment: it is a dynamic sql - sql query is generated at runtime based on some logic, preconditions etc
Unfortunately i can't substitute the parameters directly when the sql query is constructed

Comment: I'm not sure I really follow.. why wouldn't something like this work? "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME=? AND SURNAME=?".replace("NAME=?", "NAME='Selva'").replace("SURNAME=?", "SURNAME='Esra'");

Comment: On your Hibernate `Query`object, you can not only get the query string but also the list of parameters using [`getParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getParameters()). Then, you can replace all your `?` by each one of the parameters on the set.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Named parameters**

This is the most common and user friendly way. It use colon followed by a parameter name (:example) to define a named parameter. See examples…

```
String hql = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME= :userName AND SURNAME= :surName";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("userName ", "userName");
query.setParameter("surName", "SurName");
List results = query.list();
```

An object-oriented representation of a Hibernate query. A Query instance is obtained by calling Session.createQuery(). This interface exposes some extra functionality beyond that provided by Session.iterate() and Session.find():

a particular page of the result set may be selected by calling setMaxResults(), setFirstResult()
    named query parameters may be used
    the results may be returned as an instance of ScrollableResults

```
Named query parameters are tokens of the form :name in the query string. A value is bound to the integer parameter :foo by calling

setParameter("foo", foo, Hibernate.INTEGER);
```

for example. A name may appear multiple times in the query string.

JDBC-style ? parameters are also supported. To bind a value to a JDBC-style parameter use a set method that accepts an int positional argument (numbered from zero, contrary to JDBC).

You may not mix and match JDBC-style parameters and named parameters in the same query.

**2. Positional parameters**

It’s use question mark (?) to define a named parameter, and you have to set your parameter according to the position sequence. See example…
Java

```
String hql = "from Stock s where s.stockCode = ? and s.stockName = ?";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
.setString(0, "7277")
.setParameter(1, "DIALOG")
.list();
```

This approach is not support the setProperties function. In addition, it’s vulnerable to easy breakage because every change of the position of the bind parameters requires a change to the parameter binding code.
Java

```
String hql = "from Stock s where s.stockName = ? and s.stockCode = ?";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
.setParameter(0, "DIALOG")
.setString(1, "7277")
.list();
```

**Conclusion**

In Hibernate parameter binding, i would recommend always go for “Named parameters“, as it’s more easy to maintain, and the compiled SQL statement can be reuse (if only bind parameters change) to increase the performance.